# how to debug with library module (pdb)?

Tags: python, pdb

I want to print the value of a variable inside a library module, e.g., function roc_auc_score in sklearn.metrics. I imported the pdb module:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
>>> y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])

>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) b roc_auc_score
Breakpoint 1 at /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py:244
(Pdb) roc_auc_score(y_true, y_scores)
```

I expect the function will break and wait at line 224 of module 'ranking.py', but the function finished without a break. How can I make the execution stop inside of the module 'ranking.py'?

Comment: I'm curious...why do you need to resort to using the debugger at the command line?  You can't use something more sophisticated, like PyCharm or Eclipse?  You could play around quite a bit more easily, I'm sure, with a full IDE.

Comment: Knowing the way a debugger is usually used, my guess is that breakpoints aren't applied to expressions typed at the debugger prompt itself.  I'm thinking that you're usually debugging an existing piece of code rather than typing python syntax at the prompt.  So you normally set a breakpoint and then say "continue", your code starts running again, and breaks when it gets to the line you've set a breakpoint at.  When using the debugger in my IDE, I of course set breakpoints, and also often run expressions, but I don't ever want to break in those expressions.  But maybe that's supposed to work.